# Passing values from function to function in JES/Jython

Tags: jython, jes

I am learning Jython using a program called JES, and I am having trouble understanding how to return values from a function that can be used in another function.

For example:

```
def driver():
  picture = makePicture(pickAFile())
  input(picture)
  changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount)

def input(picture):
  redReduceAmount = requestInteger("How much should I reduce red by?")
  return redReduceAmount
def changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount):
  for p in getPixels(picture):
    value=getRed(p)
    setRed(p,value*0.9)
```

I want to be able to just run the driver function in the command area, and have that function include the other functions.  I understand that results in functions are local and don't pass through, but I though that if you use 'return' then it stores that value for later use.  Am I on the wrong track here?  Surely there is a way to pass information between functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Any "-" just disregard them that is not part of the code, they are just there for spacing to help so that you don't get any syntax errors.

```
def driver():
   picture = makePicture(pickAFile())
   input(picture)
   changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount)
   repaint(picture)`
```

or

```
def changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount):
   for p in getPixels(picture):
      value=getRed(p)
      setRed(p,value*0.9)
      repaint(picture)
```

or

```
def changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount):
   for p in getPixels(picture):
      value=getRed(p)
      setRed(p,value*0.9)
      show(picture)
```

or

```
def changeRed(picture, reduceRedAmount):
   for p in getPixels(picture):
      value=getRed(p)
      setRed(p,value*0.9)
   return(picture)`
```

One of those repaint, return, show should work to display the new image.

To display other values in command area just use "print something here" for example print 1+1 or print value.

Answer (score -1):

the way I do it is declare it as a global variable the line after the `def functionName()` and at the LAST line of the `functionName()` code before you reduce the indent, type `return variableNameYouWant`.

check this:

`def functionName()
   global variableNameYouWant
   ..
   ..
   return variableNameYouWant`

What we are doing by following this is declaring the function you want to be a global variable (which must be done before it is delcared with a value, so best to do at the start of the def.) and then before you close the def by decreasing indentation, return the variable outside of the def.

I know it's an old question but I'm striving for upvotes as a newbie. :)

Edit:  Thanks for the downvote, anon.